# Java, is it possible to 'convert' object from subclass to object from superclass

Tags: java, object, subclass, superclass

I have two classes Student and Tutor. Tutor is basically a student (Tutor extends Student) who has facultyID. Once his contract is complete, he returns to being just a student. So can I somehow convert him back to his "previous" roll of student?

Comment: It's possible you shouldn't use inheritance at all to model this relationship.  Based on your short description you might want to consider creating a Tutor wrapper which takes a Student at construction time.  Then when the contract is complete you can simply let the reference to the wrapper fall out of scope and continue to work with the Student instance directly.

Comment: can you provide a bit more context to your question? 
imho it really depends on what you're trying to achieve. 
maybe adding a `boolean isTutor;` member or simply keeping a list of students that are also tutors is enough. no need to model everything with OO patterns just because you can.

Comment: @kritzikratzi I love your comment "No need to model everything with OO ... just because you can". Couldn't agree more!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you really want to do here is use [composition and not inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance). Keep all your objects as type `Student`, and then temporarily assign the behaviour of a `TutorRole` as it is required to each instance of `Student`.

With this design your `Student` class will contain a property (member variable) of type `TutorRole` that you can add or remove at runtime. Adding an `isTutor()` method will allow you to detemine whether a Student is a Tutor at runtime in a clear and concise manner.

The `TutorRole` class will encapsulate the behaviour (i.e. methods) of being a Tutor.

```
/*
 * The TutorRole can be set at runtime
 */
public class Student {

    private String facultyId;

    private TutorRole tutorRole = null;

    public boolean isTutor() {
        return !(tutorRole == null);
    }

    public void doTutorStuff() {
        if(isTutor()) {
            tutorRole.doTutorStuff();
        }
        else {
            throw new NotTutorException();
        }
    }

    public void setTutorRole(TutorRole tutorRole) {
        this.tutorRole = tutorRole;
    }
}

/*
 * Ideally this class should implement a generic interface, but I'll keep this simple
 */
public class TutorRole {

    public void doTutorStuff() {
        // implementation here
    }
}

/*
 * Now let's use our classes...
 */
Student st = new Student(); // not a tutor
st.setTutorRole(new TutorRole()); // now a tutor
if(st.isTutor()) {
    st.doTutorStuff();
}
st.setTutorRole(null); // not a tutor anymore
```

An alternative approach is to have a `Tutor` class contain a reference to a `Student` object, but it depends on how you are going to be interacting with the Student and Tutor objects on which way around you want to code this.

Answer (score 4):

I think, this screams containment and interface programming.

How about this:

```
interface IStudent
{
  String getName();
  int getStudentId();
}

interface IFacultyMember
{
  int getFacultyId( );
}

class Student
  implements IStudent
{
  String name;
  int id;

  public String getName( ) { return name; }
  public int getStudentId( ) { return id; }
}

class Tutor
  implements IStudent, IFacultyMember
{
  Student student;
  int facultyId;

  public Tutor ( Student student, int facultyId )
  {
    this.student = student;
    this.facultyId = facultyId;
  }

  public String getName( ) { return student.getName( ); }
  public int getStudentId( ) { return student.getStudentId( ); }
  public int getFacultyId( ) { return facultyId; };
}
```

This way, your Student remains a student, even if it moves to the Tutor position.  When Tutor's term expires you just GC the tutor record.

Student's record, on the other hand will still be available in Central Services.

Answer (score 3):

Once you create an instance of some type (for example, `Tutor`), that's the runtime type that instance is gonna have. This can't be changed anymore.

Some alternatives:

- Give `Student` some constructor that accepts another `Student` instance and copies over the relevant fields. A so-called copy constructor. That way, you could easily create a new `Student` instance based on your `Tutor` and then use that instead.
- If it's important that the actual instance is kept rather than creating some copy (maybe you've kept references all over the place), it'd be best to separate role from class. Make some `FacultyMember` class or something and turn `Student` and `Tutor` into roles. Then you can change the role of a `FacultyMember` later on.

Answer (score 2):

You can *cast* the Tutor as a Student so your code treats him as such at compile time, but the object will remain a Tutor, so calling any overridden methods will cause the Tutor class's version to be called.

The only way to do the kind of "conversion" you're looking for is to create a new Student object and give it all the properties that the Tutor has.

Since you're finding that you need to do this conversion, you may want to re-think the class structure. For example, maybe both Students and Tutors should really just be Persons, and each Person can have the Role of Student or Teacher.

Comment: Could you please elaborate this? I'm not sure how to do that?

Comment: @vedran: If you want to edit your answer to provide some of your current code and a more full explanation of what you're trying to accomplish by converting a person from one type to another, I can give you some better feedback.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change objects type in Java. Probably the easiest way to achieve youw way is to clone all parameters from Tutor into a new Student object.

Answer (score 1):

You could just write a method like `TutorToStudent()` on Tutor and create a new Student from your Tutor. If you cast you'll end up with the object still being a Tutor.

You might also consider forgoing inheritence in this case and just have a flag indicating the whether or not this student is a Tutor.

Comment: But then if you had a collection of Students, it would still hold the old Tutor, not the new regular Student.

Comment: @glowcoder: True but this holds true for most solutions that still maintain the inheritence hierarchy and attempt to somehow turn the Tutor into a Student. Like any solution it doesn't solve all cases and extra coding will obviously be required to account for cases like you mentioned.

Comment: yes it does hold true for solutions that maintain the inheritance hierarchy. But it is good practice to "Favor composition over inheritance". It is much better to have a `Student` role and a `Tutor` role and simply have an instance (or list) of a role (or roles, if using a list).

Answer (score 1):

1. You can create a new Student with the exact same information as the Tutor and discard the original object. Either with a copy-constructor `Student(Student original)` or a `Student toStudent()` method This is the quick and dirty way.
2. Instead of making Tutor directly extend a Student, making the `Tutor` specific data and behavior into a **[Decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)**. Or better yet, make both `Tutor` and `Student` decorators of a `People` object that includes everyone. This is one of the proper ways to do this.
3. Make the `Tutor` and `Student` into a `enum Type` and hold this field in `People`, this is easier but less extensible than the above, it really depend on the nature of the differences between Tutor and Student.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as "converting" him back to a student, he is a tutor, and a tutor already IS a student.

However, there may be some value in genericizing the access of this object, so that you only use student method.  There are several idioms in java for this.

1) You can use the Student API exclusively in your code, with the exception of the Tutor portion.

2) You can have a "toStudent/toTutor" method for your objects, which allow them to return objects which are specific to the role.

//My preference 
3) You can use interfaces.  Have Tutor and Student both be interfaces, and build your objects using interface implementation.  If you refer to objects using minimal interfaces, rather than heavyweight inheritance patterns, your code will probably scale better in the future.